# How to split string into 2 parts if it is longer then 90 chars

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I have a dynamic string (in Ruby program) and I need to split it if it is longer then 91 chars. I need to split it into parts on closes comma ',' char.

String example:

```
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to "split on each comma" if the string is ore than 90 characters long, or do you want to "split on commas to make chunks as long as possible, but no longer than 90 characters each" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what you need:

```
string.split(',').in_groups_of(90, false)
```

Result:

```
> str.split(',').in_groups_of(10, false)
=> [["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"],
 ["11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"],
 ["21", "22", "23", "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30"],
 ["31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40"],
 ["41"]]
```

Or an array with joined values:

```
str.split(',').in_groups_of(10, false).map {|s| s.join(',')}
```

Result:

```
> str.split(',').in_groups_of(10, false).map {|s| s.join(',')}
=> ["1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",
 "11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20",
 "21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30",
 "31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40",
 "41"]
```

**UPDATE:**

With plain Ruby (not Rails):

```
str.split(',').each_slice(10).to_a
```

or joined:

```
str.split(',').each_slice(10).map {|s| s.join(',')}
```

Comment: xs.in_groups_of(2, false) == xs.each_slice(2).to_a. http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  str.split(',') if str.length>91
```

Comment: This will not always split the string in _two_ parts.

Comment: @tbuehlmann, why was 2 parts comes into picture. op asked to split only if its more than 91 chars...

Comment: It's not in the question - which is bad indeed - but in the title.

Comment: @tbuehlmann, in title also op said 'split string into 2 parts **if it is longer then 90 chars**'.. i dont understand the problem

Comment: Right, split into 2 (!) parts. You will split the string as often as the character `,` appears. Though I think the title is misleading and not describing the actual problem. I'd have suggested the same solution as you did, though the title says different.

Comment: @RameshVel: +1, agree with you

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you need something that takes a String and returns an Array where each element of the Array is a string with length 91 or less. But you want the resulting strings to be as long as possible before splitting on the delimiter.

```
a = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41"

def my_split(str, delimiter, max_length)
    return [str] if str.length <= max_length
    i = str.rindex(delimiter, max_length)
    the_rest = my_split(str[i+1..-1], delimiter, max_length)
    return [str[0..i-1]] + the_rest
end

for r in my_split(a, ',', 90)
    puts "#{r}:Length: #{r.length.to_s}"
end
```

results with:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33:Length: 89
34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41:Length: 23
```